# What type of different elements can a Set include?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am looking to define what a set will look like for a part of my HW. The set should include some scalar elements and some quantities like the pressure distribution for 3 dimensions that corresponds to the aforementioned scalar quantities.

My questions are: a) Is it still a set?,
b) will it be of the form S = {a, b, c, {x, y, z}} or should I consider any other form?
c) will the properties of set theory apply to such a set? and finally
d) which set theory would be most appropriate for such a set?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know what a pressure distribution is, but if they form a set $P$ and each element of $P$ corresponds to some scalar, then you may want to define your set as a subset of a Cartesian product $F \times P$, where $F$ is your set of scalars. That would answer (b), and the answers to (a) and (c) would be yes. I don't understand question (d).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A pressure distribution is, in a nutshell, pressure values on the X, Y and Z axes. What I am trying to determine is: for an engineering problem that combines both scalar and surface (multidimensional) variables, can all these different types of variables be incorporated into the same set?